# QGIS ubuntu Couldn't load SIP module

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and installed QGIS 2.18 following the official install details
[QGIS Installers](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) using link Release with ubuntugis dependencies
http://qgis.org/ubuntugis.
I have python 2.7.12 on my system. Every time I start QGIS, the error message is :

```
Couldn't load SIP module.
Python support will be disabled.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named sip
     Python version:
        2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
        [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

        QGIS version:
        2.18.0 'Las Palmas', b7fe4bb2

        Python path:
        ['/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/user/.qgis2/python', u'/home/user/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

on the python IDLE i can to import SIP module.
any idea how to fix that ?

**UPDATE**

if i run cat /etc/apt/sources.list

show me (only related to QGIS):

```
.
.
.
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
```

update i have python 2.7.12 and sip version 4.17,qt version 4.8.7,pyqt version 4.11.4
after reinstall qgis now i have that error:

```
Couldn't load SIP module.
Python support will be disabled.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsUTF8String
Python version:
2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
QGIS version:
2.18.0 'Las Palmas', b7fe4bb2
Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/user/.qgis2/python', u'/home/user/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

---

```
('Qt version:', '4.8.7') 
('SIP version:', '4.17') 
('PyQt version:', '4.11.4')
```

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Comment: ok i update sorry

Comment: Can you edit your question to put the result of this command: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` (only the QGIS corresponding part).

Comment: update with result to ask me

Comment: Try out this repository: `http://qgis.org/debian`. It is recommended first (related to Debian/Ubuntu) in this link: https://www.qgis.org/es/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu. I load **sip** module at the Python Console of my QGIS 2.18 (Debian system) without problems.

Comment: i tried na change some error again,i uninstall QGIS and install again with repository: http://qgis.org/debian and show me again that error